# Get the segment number

Tags: position, segment

let me try to explain what I want to do, with Wolfram Mathematica, with an example.
I have subdivided a 1.7 meter long rod in several segments with offsets

```
{0., 0.533, 0.617, 0.819, 1.131, 1.455, 1.511, 1.7}
```

Let me give a position, e.g. x=0.56, I want to know in which segment that x is located. In this case x belong to segment=2.
If I give x=1.15 I should get segment=5.
If I give x=1.61 I should get segment=7.
And so on.
Obviously avoiding loops.
Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Found! Thanks anyway!

```
x := 1.61;
Count[MapThread[  GreaterEqual, {x - Offs, Table[0, Length[Offs]]}], True]
```

Fist of all I get a table containing only zeros:

```
Table[0, Length[Offs]]
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

then I compare

x := 1.61; x - Offs

so I get an array containing positive numbers if x > Offs[nth element]

```
{1.61, 1.077, 0.993, 0.791, 0.479, 0.155, 0.099, -0.09}
```

The

```
MapThread[GreaterEqual, {x - Offs, Table[0, Length[Offs]]}]
```

allows to compare element by element the two arrays:

```
{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False}
```

Finally I count the "True" elements.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**